# where to place the templates of an adminhtml block?

Tags: adminhtml, extensions, template

I have a custom design called `mydesign` and a custom extension  (`My_Testmodule`).

if i create the following block in my own module:

```
class My_Testmodule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Test extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Abstract {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('mydesign/catalog/product/edit/options/type/test.phtml');
    }

}
```

where should the template be located?

should it be in

- app/design/adminhtml/mydesign/default/template/testmodule/catalog/product/...
- app/design/frontend/mydesign/default/template/testmodule/catalog/product/...
- or somewhere else?

i thought it should be in `adminhtml/...` but it doesn't seems to be called. The Block is definitly beeing called, if i echo something in constructor it will be printed on screen. But the template seems to be ignored.

Please help me, im struggeling arround with it since hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Magento does not offer a package/theme setting for the admin section and it uses default/default

Placing your template into
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mydesign/catalog/product/edit/options/type/test.phtml`
should do the trick.

Theme fallback also works so you can use
`app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/mydesign/catalog/product/edit/options/type/test.phtml`
as well, but I haven't seen `base` used widely for admin themes yet.

*Further reading*
If you want to be able to use a custom admin theme (app/design/adminhtml/mydesign/default/) please see [this blog post](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/custom-adminhtml-theme) outlining different options.

Comment: in general i do not want to use a custom admin theme at this time. What i want to do is to create an extension with a custom product options type. This requires some new Blocks in admin section. So i have learned that we should not change the magento code to be able to update magento and to have a clean structure. If i place the template in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/...` isn't it a modification of magentos source files? What happens if i upgrade to a new magento version?

Comment: To avoid any issues I would suggest keeping your templates in their own subfolder named after your company/namespace. So unless someone else is using the very same name you are fine. And of course overwriting any existing files is a no go. This approach works across updates since you are not editing any existing Magento core files.